# C# add roles to user programatically using checklist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I want to add multiple roles to one user, currently I add one role to a user, I want the possibility to add multiple roles

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindRolesToList();
        CheckBoxList.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = CreateUserWizard1.UserName;
        foreach (ListItem listItem in CheckBoxList.Items)
        {
            if (listItem.Selected)
            {
                string role = CheckBoxList.SelectedValue;
                Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, role);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }


        CheckBoxList.Visible = false;
    }
    private void BindRolesToList() {    
        string[] roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();      
        CheckBoxList.DataSource = roles;
        CheckBoxList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

This only adds one role to a user. how would I add more than one role to a user from a checkboxlist?

EDIT: Just checked my users in WAT, and turns out it doesnt add any role to the user at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add pass the ListItem Value

```
   if (listItem.Selected)
    {
        string role = listItem.Value;
        Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, role);
    }
    else
    {

    }
```